# Adding rules JQuery validation not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, validation

I'm adding JQuery validation rules dinamically with the function below:

```
function addRules(rulesObj) {
    for (item in rulesObj) {
        $('#' + item).rules('add', rulesObj[item]);
    }
}
```

I'm using JQuery version 1.7.2 and JQuery validate 1.9 and it is not working in IE 7 and 8. Works fine in Chrome and FF. Am I missing anything? 
The error: `Object doesn't support this action.`

The rule looks like this:

```
var ctrxRules = {
        L4 : {
            required : true
             }
};
```

**If the rule is empty it works.**

Comment: I tried replicating this, but wasn't successful. Would you mind providing an example on http://fiddle.net that demonstrates this?

Comment: The answer below solved the problem.

Comment: I understand, however I'm curious *how* it solved the problem. Can you please provide an example of your faulty code via http://fiddle.net, so that we can better document the issue? As @Ryley said, he was unable to actually *explain* the reason why the code worked.

Comment: Well everything is on my computer at work. I didn't use any script debugger on IE but when I commented the addRules function or commented the body the page loaded. There is not much more I can say, I've stated the versions of JQuery, JQuery validate and IE

Comment: I'll come up with the code tomorrow.. but it's pretty big.

Comment: I would appreciate that. It's all part of furthering research and making StackOverflow a more helpful place. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't explain why, but the solution is simple, add a `var` before item:

```
function addRules(rulesObj) {
    for (var item in rulesObj) {
        $('#' + item).rules('add', rulesObj[item]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably because declaring the variable without keyword 'var' pollutes the global scope with the 'item'